# Create arbitrary dimension sparse matrix in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

So I'm using Python 3 to create a matrix of the form

```
L=[B 0 0
   0 B 0
   0 0 B]
```

where

```
B=[4 -1  0
  -1  4 -1
   0 -1  4]
```

But instead of repeating `B` three times, I want to do it `N` times (depending on input). My shot so far is the following

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

one=np.ones(N)
four=4*np.ones(N)
data = np.array([-one, four, -one])
diags = np.array([-1,0, 1])
B=sp.spdiags(data, diags, N, N).toarray() # Create matrix B

L=np.kron(np.eye(N), B)
```

However, it takes a lot of time when `N` is big (which is necessary since this is to solve a differential equation). Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: Do you need a sparse matrix result?  Dense array construction is nearly always faster, but does hit memory limits sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No timings here (no performance guarantees from me), but for me the most natural approach (don't have much experience with kronecker) would be scipy's [block_diag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html#scipy.sparse.block_diag) although i always wonder if i'm using it correctly (in this case: list-comprehension):

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

N = 2
B = np.array([[4,-1,0],[-1,4,-1],[0,-1,4]])
L = sp.block_diag([B for i in range(N)])

print(L.todense())
```

#### Out

```
[[ 4 -1  0  0  0  0]
 [-1  4 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  4  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  4 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1  4]]
```

Comment: `sparse.kron` is faster.  But still slower than the `np.kron`.

Comment: @hpaulj Would you consider my usage of the inner list-comprehension good practice? I always wonder if it is (and did not check the internals yet). Ignoring API-support three ideas of passing the block-matrix come to mind: a generator, a list-comprehension or a numpy array. I assume scipy needs access to *len* so a generator doesn't do it probably. On the other hand, building a dense-representation a-priori (with repetitions) is not very memory-efficient (for this use-case). Any remarks? Would there be some merit for some memory-efficient lazy-like generator support incl. a-priori dimensions?

Comment: Look at the code for `block_diag`.  It expects a list of matrices, which it then turns into the nest list input that `sparse.bmat` expects.  `bmat` then collects the `coo` attributes of all the matrices, assembles them with appropriate offsets, and makes a new much larger `coo` matrix.  It works, but internally is not very pretty.